# Does high overall avg write latency on core app db data file and temp db data file due to brief period of pressure have any remedy?

Tags: sql-server, performance

My read and write latency throught the day is between 5ms to 20ms, across all drives.

There is a heavy process that runs at around 5pm for 30-min during which the write latency for the core application data file and the tempdb data file goes to about 600 to 3000ms.

Now this is causing:

1. Some users complain on slowness
2. The *overall* (since reboot) write latency of the data and tempdb data file shows as 120ms.

The SAN admin agrees that SQL server is making extensive writes between 5pm to 5.30pm.

What can I do to remediate this? This heavy process at each run (every day 5pm) creates a new table and writes into it (the daily financial transaction reconcilation data). There are no indexes on this table.

Comment: TBH, this sounds more of like an infrastructure problem rather than a SQL Server problem. 3 seconds of write latency is not normal under any data load. But probably more information is needed to troubleshoot your actual root issue. I'd recommend starting with the disks directly with a [Crystal Disk Mark](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/03/how-fast-your-san-or-how-slow/) test. If that causes similarly slow metrics, then nothing you can do on SQL Server will fix this, other than writing less data at a time.

Comment: Been testing this and observed that the process writes 20GB of data in spam of 30mins. Of this 18GB is written between the 20th to 30th minutes. The SAN admin agrees he is observing severe IO spike during this period. I will learn about crystal disk mark. Is this tool better or shall I use diskspd. Not used either before so a sample parameter will be helpful for me to start with..

Comment: Both tools are equally helpful but I find Crystal Disk Mark easier to use, especially because of its GUI. The link I sent you in my previous comment is a full Brent Ozar article on how to use it properly, and how to interpret the results.

Comment: Btw 20 GB of data written in 30 minutes is about 11 MB/s of write speed. That's absolutely terrible. A mechanical hard drive is rated at anywhere between 10x-50x faster than that.

Comment: @J.D. - what is the implication of having high write latency to the app db and tempdb data files? I believe that SQL engine primarily requires low write latency to log file, and low reads latency to data file. In my case this is between 5ms to 10ms.